# Android Version 8 - Bluetooth Package

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, package, share

My application works for android 2.3.3. But for version 8, android 2.2 when I try to send file via bluetooth it says that I dont have bluetooth! And I have it!

I am using this:

```
file = new FileSystem(this).saveTemp(onlineConfig);

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

sharingIntent.setType("spacesyntax/onlineconfig");
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share SpaceSyntaxOnlineConfig Using"));
```

Maybe the package for bluetooth is different at version 8? How can I check Android version at run time? And which package android 8 has for bluetooth?

Comment: I don't know much about Bluetooth (never used it yet in a project) but maybe you can find here something http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html , Bluetooth is added in API 5, so API 8 (Android 2.2) should have it already)

Comment: The package name for bluetooth is same from API 5: `com.android.bluetooth`

Comment: Okay I found the problem, was the mime type :) 
Changed it to image/png and it works now, but I can't send the file from android 2.2 why? it says: failed by user . what the hell? In the other device I am discoverable...